# Cannot receive reward for field-research

Tags: pokemon-go

Today I am on the last day of the field-research quests.

I have already collected about 8 stamps today but I still cannot receive the reward: nothing happens if I click on the big orange button.

If I close the window it jumps back to "You need 1 more stamp to receive ....". I already tried to disable / enable WiFi and to restart the game multiple times, with no effect.

Anyone got an idea what could I do ?

Comment: First things that comes to mind is that you are not really on the last day of the field research. Is there a big button with `Claim rewards`?

Comment: @Mathias711 I am sure ! I even get the message from the Professor that I've just cleared everything. Then the big orange button comes up (half the screen), but when I press it nothing happens.

Comment: It's worth a shot, but is your Pokemon storage full? [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/8hkvty/useless_psa_you_cant_claim_a_research_reward/) reddit posts states you can't claim research rewards if your Pokemon storage is full

Comment: @Wondercricket that was just it ... Did not thought about that :D If u want to post this as an official answer please go for it !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the discussion within the comments, it would appear your storage is full. According to [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/8hkvty/useless_psa_you_cant_claim_a_research_reward/) post, you are unable to collect field research rewards with a full inventory. It would be safe to assume this accounts for both Pokémon Storage and Item Storage.

The solution to this is to transfer Pokémon and/or drop items to make room for your rewards.

> [image]